# "partir pour" or "partir à"

Tags: prépositions

> Je pars pour Paris

and

> Je pars à Paris

I've seen both versions used to say "I am leaving for Paris". Is there a difference between the two versions? Are both correct?

Comment: *Je pars à Paris* is always right. *Je pars pour Paris* sounds like you don't know if you will come back, or even you know you won't come back. Like a French soldier during WWII saying *Je pars pour l'Allemagne, adieu mes amis*. Or if it's for a long trip, or if you leave the city you've always lived in. It sounds a bit dramatic to me, like if going there is something important with consequences, changing your life. However, it's true that you can hear it in everyday situations for ordinary trips too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both forms are nowadays correct and have mostly the same meaning however ***partir pour*** used to be the rule and still is for some grammarians.

The form ***partir à*** + destination was considered incorrect when it appeared in the 19th century. You had to say ***partir pour*** and ***aller à***. The rationale was *partir* means to leave a place but *à + location* implies the destination is part of the action which is only the case with *aller*.

***Partir à*** is now accepted and common, especially in spoken French. Ref.: [*Académie Française*](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/guillaume-de-v-france) unless the departure location is also present:

> *Je pars de Lyon pour Paris* is much better than *Je pars de Lyon à Paris*.

Note that ***pour*** can be used whatever the destination while ***à*** can't  with some kinds of destinations, e.g.:

> *Partir en Italie* / *partir pour l'Italie* but not <s>*partir à l'Italie*.</s>
>
> *Partir dans les Alpes* / *partir pour les Alpes* but not <s>*partir aux alpes*</s> / <s>*partir en Alpes*.</s>

As usual, ***à***+***le/les*** changes in ***au/aux***:

> Partir au Pôle Nord / Partir pour le Pôle Nord.
>
> Partir aux États-Unis / Partir pour les États-Unis.

Beware that with many other verbs than ***partir***, ***pour*** instead of ***à*** might change the meaning of the sentence or just won't be possible:

> *Je reviens à Paris* : I'm coming back to Paris.

vs

> *Je reviens pour Paris* : I'm coming back because of Paris.

---

> *J'arrive à Paris* : I'm arriving in Paris.

vs

> *<s>J'arrive pour Paris.</s>* : meaningless, or at least doesn't mean the same as the previous sentence.

---

> *Je vais à Rio* : I'm going to Rio.

vs

> *<s>Je vais pour Rio</s>* : impossible.

---

You wouldn't use either *pour* twice like in:

> *Je pars pour Paris pour une semaine.*

Ugly

> *Je pars à Paris pour une semaine.*

Fine, unless you don't like Paris of course ;-)

Comment: @Faʁdɔʃɔtɔmatabaʁwɛt Merci, mais je n'ai pour l'instant que 19978 points ;-)

Comment: Ouais désolé, donc félicitations pour ce 20k ;-)

Answer (score 1):

**partir + destination précise: à**

> Je pars à Paris, à Venise, à Rome, à Berlin.

**partir + direction, objet, ou sans précision sur la destination finale: pour**

> Je pars pour des vacances, pour oublier, pour ne plus revenir.
>
> Je pars pour Paris, pour le Mexique (mais peut-être vais-je changer de
>   direction en route ...)

**En revanche, avec le verbe aller, seul *à* est possible.**

Comment: @jlliagre  erreur de frappe - merci.